# I am using image picker to open camera and select images in flutter and it works perfectly fine for android devices but in IOS it won't work

Tags: ios, flutter

Here I am using image picker to open camera (or even gallery) and select images in flutter and it works perfectly fine for android devices but in IOS when I click "browse" button which is supposed to open camera it navigates to "Settings" instead and it doesn't show any error either, I have added everything in info.plist as required too.[This is ss of info.plist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6btvA.png)

Answer (score 0):

Goto image picker doc page and implement ios setup.